# How do I control config names?

Tags: entities, configuration, importing-exporting

When creating a config entity, we get an example_entity.schema.yml file:

```
example_module.example_entity.*:
  type: config_entity
  label: 'Example config'
  mapping:
    id:
      type: string
      label: 'ID'
    label:
      type: label
      label: 'Label'
    uuid:
      type: string
```

Creating entities of this type will result in config names, where the asterisk is replaced with the "id" property of the entity:

```
example_module.example_entity.name_1
example_module.example_entity.name_2
...
```

But how to control, which property is used and how to add support for more properties? For example, in core's
`core.entity_form_display.*.*.*`, what is mapping the entity type to first wildcard, the entity bundle to second and the display mode to third?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remainder of the config name is by definition the ID:

*core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Entity/ConfigEntityStorage.php*

```
 * Configuration object names of configuration entities are comprised of two
 * parts, separated by a dot:
 * - config_prefix: A string denoting the owner (module/extension) of the
 *   configuration object, followed by arbitrary other namespace identifiers
 *   that are declared by the owning extension; e.g., 'node.type'. The
 *   config_prefix does NOT contain a trailing dot. It is defined by the entity
 *   type's annotation.
 * - ID: A string denoting the entity ID within the entity type namespace; e.g.,
 *   'article'. Entity IDs may contain dots/periods. The entire remaining string
 *   after the config_prefix in a config name forms the entity ID. Additional or
 *   custom suffixes are not possible.
```

However, it is possible for the config entity class to override `id()` with a computed compound ID. Like in the example you've mentioned:

*core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityDisplayBase.php*

```
  public function id() {
    return $this->targetEntityType . '.' . $this->bundle . '.' . $this->mode;
  }
```